# Passing argument from View text input to Controller parameter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I want to pass an input from my main view "Index" to a Controller, here is the Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult AppointmentsByClient(String name_Client)
    {
        //name_Client = "Diana";
        var appointments = appointmentService.getAppointmentsByClientName(name_Client);
        Console.WriteLine(name_Client);
        return View(appointments);
    }
```

Here is the input from the main view index.cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name_Client" />
    </div>
```

and name_Client is null everytime i cant pass the value.

Comment: Can you show the whole view pls?

Comment: Try changing `GET` to `POST`, also putting the `input` inside a `form`

Comment: I tried with post but then i get an error that i have null values inside the view where i post data.

Answer (score 1):

Create view model

```
public class ViewModel
{
 public string ClientName {get; set;}
 public  List<Tema2_NoLogin.Models.Appointment>  Appointements {get; set;}
}
```

In your index view add form tag

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AppointmentsByClient";
}

@model Tema2_NoLogin.Models.ViewModel 

<div class="container p-3">
    <div class="row pt-4">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Appointments By Client Name</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />


 <form method="get" asp-action="AppointmentsByClient">

    <div class="form-group">
     
    <input asp-for="ClientName" id="clientName" class="form-control" />

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Appointment By Client" class="btn btn-danger" />
    </div>

 </form>
......
@if (Model!=null && Model.Appointments!=null && Model.AppointmentsCount > 0)
    {
       .....
                @foreach (var appointment in Model.Appointments)
                {
          ..................
                }
     }
....
```

and action

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult AppointmentsByClient(ViewModel model)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(model.ClientName);

   model.Appointments = appointmentService.getAppointmentsByClientName(model.ClientName);
 
        return View(model);
    }
```

And change another view accordingly this one

Answer (score 0):

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

@model IEnumerable<Tema2_NoLogin.Models.Appointment> 

<div class="container p-3">
    <div class="row pt-4">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Appointments</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <a asp-controller="Appointment" asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary">Create new Appointment</a>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="name_Client" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <a asp-controller="Appointment" asp-action="AppointmentsByClient" class="btn btn-primary">Get Appointments By Client</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />

    @if (Model.Count() > 0)
    {
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
            <thread>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Name Client
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Phone Number
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Services
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Appointment Date
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Total
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thread>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var appointment in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td width="30%">@appointment.Id</td>
                        <td width="30%">@appointment.Name_client</td>
                        <td width="30%">@appointment.Phone_number</td>
                        <td width="30%">@appointment.AppointmentAsString</td>
                        <td width="30%">@appointment.Appointment_date</td>
                        <td width="30%">@appointment.Total</td>
                        <td width="40%">
                            <div class="col-6 text-right">
                                <a asp-controller="Appointment" asp-action="AddService" asp-route-Id="@appointment.Id" class="btn btn-primary mx-1">Add service</a>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
    else
    {
        <p>No Appointments</p>
    }



</div>

<h1>Index</h1>
```

This is the whole view

Answer (score 0):

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AppointmentsByClient";
}

@model IEnumerable<Tema2_NoLogin.Models.Appointment>  

<div class="container p-3">
    <div class="row pt-4">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Appointments By Client Name</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name_Client" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="AppointmentByClient" class="btn btn-danger" />
    </div>
    <form method="get" asp-action="AppointmentsByClient">

        @if (Model.Count() != 0)
        {
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
                <thread>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            ID
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Name Client
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Phone Number
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Services
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Appointment Date
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Total
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thread>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var appointment in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td width="30%">@appointment.Id</td>
                            <td width="30%">@appointment.Name_client</td>
                            <td width="30%">@appointment.Phone_number</td>
                            <td width="30%">@appointment.AppointmentAsString</td>
                            <td width="30%">@appointment.Appointment_date</td>
                            <td width="30%">@appointment.Total</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
        else
        {
            <p>No Appointments</p>
        }

    </form>


</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

This the view where i post the data that i get from the controller.

Comment: everything looks good , only please copy and paste it  to your question and delete this and the next answer too.